# Make div size exactly text width?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to keep an icon floated left on a liquid text container that has line breaks.

The problem is that when the line breaks, there is a large gap before the text ends and where the div ends. Which makes my floated element start where the gap ends.

Is there a way to make the div only the size of its contents?

Check this codepen: https://jsfiddle.net/e38edtdy/1/ 
Resize the output area to see the gap of space. 
The button will auto resize it to see the gap.

```
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
top:0;
left:0;
  }
 #mainContainer{
 width:100%;
      border:black solid thin;
}

 #lt{
 color: black;
 background-color:gray;
 tex-align:left;
 max-width:90%;
float:left;

}
#icon{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
}

<body  >

  <div id='mainContainer'>
    <div id='lt'>This is The information This is The information This is The information</div>
    <div id='icon'></div>

  </div>
  <br/>
  <input type='button' onClick='showBadSize()' value="click to auto resize to show gap" style='margin-top:20px;float:left; clear:left' />
</body>
```

Comment: An element doesn't know when its content wrap, so to solve this you need a script

Comment: @LGSon so there is no css solution to get my goal? Can you please provide link to the exact duplicate?

Comment: No, there is no CSS solution, and the duplicate link is at the top of your question

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for you might be to put `hyphens: auto` on your text container to make text break more nicely. Firefox needed a language attribute as well, like `lang='en-US'`.

Comment: We don't answer with a link to another answer, we vote to close as a duplicate. Additionally do what I did, add a comment with a suggestion